# Draw a curve in the segmented image using matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

I have a segmented image as shown here [image]

i want to fit a curve along the top pixels of the segmented image(show as red curve) and i want to find the top point along the curve show in blue.[image] I have already worked on basic idea like traversing through the top to bottom and collecting the top point along each column. i want to know is there any easy solution for this problem like directly taking out the boundary pixels and find the top point.I am using MATLAB for this problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
%download the image
img = logical(imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/or2iX.png'));
%for some reason it appeared RGB with big solid borders.
%to monochrome
img = img(:,:,1);
%remove borders
img = img(~all(img,2), ~all(img,1));
%split into columns
cimg = num2cell(img,1);
%find first nonzero element per column
ridx = cellfun(@(x) find(x,1,'first'), cimg);
figure, imshow(img)
hold on
%image dim1 is Y, dim2 is X
plot(1:size(img,2),ridx-1,'r','linewidth',2)
%find top point
[yval, xval] = min(ridx);
```

If you want a smoother curve, try polyfit/polyval

@EDIT
If we want the line to have break at gaps between connected components, we should change the code to something like

```
bord_idx = sub2ind(size(img), ridx, 1:size(img,2));
regs=regionprops(bwlabel(img),'pixelidxlist');
regs_idx = struct2cell(regs);
split_step = cellfun(@(x) sum(ismember(bord_idx,x)), regs_idx);
split_step = split_step(split_step>0);
split_yvals = mat2cell(ridx',split_val);
split_xvals = mat2cell([1:size(img,2)]',split_val);
figure, imshow(img)
hold on
for k = 1:length(split_step),
 plot(split_xvals{k}, split_yvals{k}, 'r', 'linewidth', 2),
end
```

However, the result is not ideal if one region is positioned over the other. If the "shadowed" points are needed, you should try bwtraceboundary or convexhull and find where the border turns down

Comment: thanks for reply ..although there is one more thing which i forget to mention. what if i don't want to interpolate between two points if there is not point present in between. Updated the image

Comment: is changing plotstile to plot(1:size(img,2),ridx-1,'rs','markerfacecolor','r') enough? If not, completely different approach is needed  there is needed,and I'll take a break and post a new reply.

Comment: Suggested one more, but still not perfect workaround

Answer (score 1):

As far as "simplest matlab solution" by which I think you mean built in matlab functions: imclose()->edge()->bwboundaries()->findpeaks()'on each boundary'->'filter results based on width and magnitude of peaks'. *you will need to tune all the parameters in these functions, I am just listing what would get you there if appropriately applied.

As far as processing speed is concerned, I think I would have done exactly what you did, basically collecting the top edge from a top down column search and then looking for the point of highest inflection.  As soon as you start doing processing of any type, you start doing several operations per pixel which will quickly become more expensive than your initial search (just requires that your image and target are simple enough)

That being said, here are some ideas that may help:

1:If you run a sufficiently heavy closing (dilate->erode), that should fill in all that garbage at the bottom.

2: If you know that your point of interest is not at left or right of picture (boundaries), you could take the right and left edge points and calculate a slope to be applied as an offset to flatten the whole image.

3: If your image always has the large dark linear region below the peak as seen here, you could locate those edges with houghlines looking for verticals and then search only the columns between them.

4: If speed is a concern, you could do a more sophisticated search pattern than left to right, as your peak has a pretty good distribution around it which could help with faster localization of maxima.